# SQL sum of numbers grouped by name, month, year

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table

```
Name | Number | Date
ACB  |      2 | 01.01.1970
ACB  |      3 | 02.01.1970
ABC  |      1 | 01.02.1970
DEF  |     10 | 01.01.1970
DEF  |     20 | 01.02.1970
```

I am looking for an SQL Query that gives me a result like this

```
Name | Sum | Month | Year
ABC  |   5 |    01 | 1970
ABC  |   1 |    02 | 1970
DEF  |  10 |    01 | 1970
DEF  |  20 |    02 | 1970
```

What I can do is get a sum over all entries of one name

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Number) AS Sum FROM table GROUP BY Name
```

As soon as is try something like the following I get an error "'mon' was not found in table"

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Number) AS Sum, MONTH(Date) AS mon FROM table GROUP BY Name, mon
```

Including the MONTH() function in the GROUP statement doesn't help either, the DB throws an "unexpected '('" error in this case.

Thanks for help!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: MySQL date and time functions require data.time data types; if you're showing us your dates in MM.DD.YYYY format, it is unlikely you are storing your dates appropriately. If it is a new database, or even an old one you can feasibly change, I would fix the table structure; if you can't, you'll need to do your own string parsing using string functions, rather than date ones.

Comment: What data type is the `Date` column?  It doesn't look like a date format.

Comment: Also, is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? If MySQL were going to error on that, it probably would've been on the MONTH() "call"; but some versions of SQL Server do not allow using the aliases from the SELECT in the GROUP BY.

Comment: You're not making a whole lot of sense. You see, it's impossible to generate that error message from that query, on that table.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any further information on the System than it is most likely a MySQL 5.6. Date functions work on my Date colum, thus no problem on this side. Also it is possible to generate these error messages, I have them on my screen (just not in english).

Answer (score 4):

The `GROUP BY` clause specifies the unique rows in the result set.  You want month and year, so that should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Number) AS Sum, MONTH(Date) AS mon, YEAR(Date) as year
FROM table
GROUP BY Name, MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date) ;
```

Comment: As stated in the last sentence, adding those functions to to GROUP BY statement throws an error.

Comment: @l487804 . . . What kind of error?  This syntax should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subquery` instead :

```
select distinct Name, MONTH(Date) AS mon, YEAR(Date) as year,
       (select sum(t1.Number) 
        from table t1 
        where t1.Name = t.Name and
              MONTH(t1.Date) = MONTH(t.Date) and 
              YEAR(t1.Date) =  YEAR(t.Date)
       ) as Sum
from table t;
```